# Unable to get my javascript to work on my website - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, javascript

I have some javascript here that seems to run fine as a snippet, but I am having a hard time trying to get it to work on my website. I've tried many plug-ins to no avail.

My question is; can someone help me upload this javascript to my website? The page I want it to work on is https://cruxstickers.com/zztest .

Thanks for any and all help!

```js
$("#product-details-continue").click(function() {

  var addr = "https://cruxstickers.com/product/" +
      $("input[type=radio][name=variant_id]:checked").val() + "-" +
      $("input[type=radio][name=quantity]:checked").val();

  alert(addr);

  // change the addr to relevant URLs and do this instead...
  // location.href = addr;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="variant-options" class="options">
<li><input type="radio" id="variant_79" name="variant_id" value="2x2" readonly=""><label for="variant_79"> 2" x 2"</label></li>
<li><input type="radio" id="variant_78" name="variant_id" value="3x3"><label for="variant_78"> 3" x 3"</label></li>
</ul>

<div id="quantities" class="product-option-group">
<legend>Select a quantity</legend>
<ul id="variant-quantities" class=" options radio"><li class="checked quantity-item"><span class="table-cell"><input type="radio" id="quantity_50" readonly="" name="quantity" value="50">
<label for="quantity_50" class="checked quantity"> 50</label></span></li>

<li class=" quantity-item"><span class="table-cell"><input type="radio" id="quantity_100" readonly="" name="quantity" value="100"><label for="quantity_100" class=" quantity"> 100</label></span></li>
<li class=" quantity-item"><span class="table-cell"><input type="radio" id="quantity_200" readonly="" name="quantity" value="200"><label for="quantity_200" class=" quantity"> 200</label></span></li>

</ul>
</div>

<button id="product-details-continue">continue</button>
```

**Below is my final javascript solution. I've added this to my wordpress themes functions.php file.**

```
add_action('wp_footer',function(){
    ?>
    <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#product-details-continue").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;


    var vrnt = jQuery("input[name=variant_id]:checked").val();
    var qnty = jQuery("input[name=quantity]:checked").val();

    var addr = "https://cruxstickers.com/product/" + vrnt + "-" + qnty;

    window.location.assign(addr);

    return false;
  });
});
    </script>
    <?php
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the JS is wrong:

In the browser Developer/Web Inspector > Console on your site, I typed `$()` and got "undefined". I then did `jQuery()`, and it shows a value, so it is defined. So you should be using `jQuery(`, not `$(` throughout.

Sidenote: I see the continue button is simply a `<button>` element, not within a `<form>`, but if it will be, with `.click()` you'll want to prevent the default button click action. You do this with:

```
yourButton.click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault;
  // your code
  return false; 
});
```

--

So I was able to get the button click to fire, through console, with this:

```
jQuery("#product-details-continue").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  alert('');
});
```

Not necessary, but you may also want to consider wrapping your jQuery in `ready` to ensure your DOM is fully loaded,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#product-details-continue").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;

    // your code
    alert('');

    return false;
  });
});
```

Adding in your code, I could get the URL popup with input values via the console with:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#product-details-continue").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;


    var vrnt = jQuery("input[name=variant_id]:checked").val();
    var qnty = jQuery("input[name=quantity]:checked").val();

    var addr = "https://cruxstickers.com/product/" + vrnt + "-" + qnty;

    alert(addr);

    return false;
  });
});
```

---

[image]

---

Secondly, to get this into your site, in your theme's functions.php file, or in your plugins main .php file - where ever you're developing out of - you can add the following to inject the JS code into the footer of your site:

```
add_action('wp_footer',function(){
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery("#product-details-continue").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault;

        var vrnt = jQuery("input[name=variant_id]:checked").val();
        var qnty = jQuery("input[name=quantity]:checked").val();

        var addr = "https://cruxstickers.com/product/" + vrnt + "-" + qnty;

        alert(addr);

        return false;
      });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
});
```

---

Lastly, you pasted HTML with a script tag for `https://ajax.googleapis..../jquery.min.js` but you don't need that, and it wasn't working. If you browse your source code, you'll see you have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cruxstickers.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4"></script>
```

already, that's why jQuery [no-conflict mode](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) `jQuery()` was working. If you were to use your external script, you should enque it into your Wordpress theme properly with [wp_enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).

Comment: Okay - so I've added the add_action() section letter for letter from the bottom of your response into my theme's function.php file and the waving alert is firing! I tried replacing that alert with the var function from my first post, and it becomes unresponsive again. Also, I have no idea what "neque your main jaunty file" means, can you elaborate?

Comment: I miss typed, *enque. Did you change `$("input[t..` to `jQuery("input[t...` in your code?.

Comment: I did change it to jQuery - also, i do not know how to enque my main jaunty file. what is a jaunty file?

Comment: Lol- jQuery*. I should not type on phone. I can sort this all out when I get on computer- unless someone else beats me to it.

Comment: Ah, so enque my main jQuery file. I do not have a main jQuery file - or at least don't know how to find it.

Comment: I've updated the post. JS is copy/paste now & I explained the enque thing.

Comment: Thanks so much - the javascript is working perfectly. In my edit you will see the action I have added to my themes functions.php file. Also, I have replaced the alert(); function with window.location.assign(); so that the continue button navigates you to the associated URL. I also have removed the google api script tag from my html. Thanks for helping me find a solution!!

Comment: p.s. Is there a difference in performance in using the no-conflict mode jQuery and using external scripts? Or is it a matter of just using whatever work for your application?

Comment: during dev it doesn't matter - but on a live site you'll want to use local scripts always - for performance, security, and validation. Besides not domain sharding, wiith local files .js/.jpg/.wtv, on your server you can assign things like Apache `mod_expire` and `mod_deflate`, which will help with PageSpeed and performance.

Comment: So, is my posted solution considered a local script since it is in my functions.php file?

Comment: by "local" i mean you're hosting it, your files on your server. "external" I meant is from remote server, like google.

Comment: You don't need to replace `$` with `jQuery` throughout, just on the first wrapper if you define the $ in the function, like this: `jQuery(document).ready(function($){ ... });` - so then `$` can be used within the rest of the code as normal.